# calling a method from UITextLabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a method called -(IBAction)setPicker:(id) sender

Basically this method substitutes a keyboard into a datePicker when called upon. I want this to happen (aka the method setPicker to be called) as soon as the user touches the text field trying to input something. The problem is that no matter what event I link it too, it does not end up calling the method.

I tried connecting the text field to the event "touch up inside" (thought I could do it the same way as I would for a button but no luck).

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

Implement the method

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

from `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Show your datepicker when this delegate method get called.

Comment: This may be very obvious but I am confused how to implement this? I have a UITextField called "month". My picker is called datePick. Within this method you noted, I put this:  self.month.inputView = self.datePick;          but nothing happens when I select the text field. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a delegate method for the UITextField .

```
(i.e `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField)`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want show UIDatePicker (or any other view) instead of keyboard when editing UITextField, you can do following:

```
UITextField* textField = ...; // your textfield
UIDatePicker* picker = ...; //your picker (or any other view)

textField.inputView = picker;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the Delegate to your Textfield..

```
textField.delegate = self;
```

I have just use this method to do the same :-

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return NO;
}
```

Hope it helps you..